# Submit One Form to Different Databases in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, api, angular-ngmodel

I create a form that has 3 difference behaviour buttons and several disabled inputs and 3 enabled inputs. First 'Approve', when the user clicks a button, values in disabled inputs and two enabled inputs that are 'Note for Support' and 'Team Support' will be saved in Approved ticket database. The second button is 'Send Back' if a user clicks the button, values in disabled inputs and one enabled input that is 'Note' will be saved in Send Back Ticket database. The last button is 'Cancel' if a user clicks the button, values in disabled inputs and one enabled input that is 'Note' will be saved in Canceled Ticket database.

I want to save the values to database by API and the disabled inputs have values from another database.

I don't have any idea to do this.
Can anyone help me?
This is the code.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="ticketManajer">
          <div class="box-body">
            <fieldset disabled>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disabledTextInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ticket Number</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>           
            <fieldset disabled>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disabledTextInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date Complain</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" value="{{data.tanggal}}">
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset disabled>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputCategory" class="col-md-2 control-label">Manager</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" value="Abu Hudzaefah" ng-model="inboxManajer.manajer">
              </div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputTextArea" class="col-md-2 control-label">Note</label>
              <div class="col-md-10" >
                 <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- CLIENT INFORMATION -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="box box-solid box-primary" style="height:350px;">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title"> Client Information </h3>
        </div>
          <div class="box-body">
            <fieldset disabled>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disabledTextInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" value="{{data.nama}}">
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>           
            <fieldset disabled>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disabledTextInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" value="{{data.email}}">
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset disabled>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disabledTextInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Handphone Number</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" value="{{data.hp}}">
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset disabled>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disabledTextInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" value="{{data.perusahaan}}">
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Client Information-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="box box-solid box-primary" style="height:350px;">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title"> Detail Complain Ticket </h3>
        </div>
          <div class="box-body">
            <fieldset disabled>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="disabledTextInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" value="{{data.judul}}">
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputCategory" class="col-md-2 control-label">Category</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" value="{{data.kategori}}">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputType" class="col-md-2 control-label">Type</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" value="{{data.tipe}}">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputTextArea" class="col-md-2 control-label">Description</label>
              <div class="col-md-10" >
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" disabled>{{data.deskripsi}}</textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Detail Designation Of Team Support -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="box box-solid box-primary" style="height:350px;">
        <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="box-title">Designation of Team Support</h3>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputType" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name</label>
              <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                  <option selected="selected" value="Amel">Amel</option>
                  <option value="Azka">Azka</option>
                  <option value="Agisha">Agisha</option>
                  <option value="Dendi">Dendi</option>
                  <option value="Fandi">Fandi</option>
                  <option value="Manda">Manda</option>
                  <option value="Putri">Putri</option>
                  <option value="Rizki">Rizki</option>
                  <option value="Rizki">Rizki</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputTextArea" class="col-md-2 control-label">Note</label>
              <div class="col-md-10" >
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4">Note for Support</textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12"><center>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i> Approve</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-vk"><i class="fa fa-reply fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Send Back</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-google"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</i>Cancel</button>
      </center></div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Fairly easy to set the `type` in a `ng-click` function. Then parse data to send and where to send it based on that type